# gtsummary::add_ci how to customize the add_ci to one decimal place?

Tags: gtsummary

I created a tbl_summary and added the confidence intervals column. I'm having challenges to set the confidence intervals to one decimal place.

[The current output obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXgq3.png) using the following code

```
db_rv_all %>% 
      select(rotavaccine_card,before_after) %>% 
      tbl_summary(by = before_after,
      statistic = rotavaccine_card ~ "{p}% ({n}/{N})",
      missing = "no",
      digits = list(all_categorical()~c(1,0,0))) %>% 
      add_difference() %>% 
      add_ci(style_fun = everything() ~ purrr::partial(style_sigfig, scale = 100))
```

The proportions column was set to one decimal place, however the I'm having challenges to set the confidence intervals to one decimal place, instead of 76%, 81%, should be 76.4%, 81.3%.

Comment: Dear @Marijn thank you for the insight, the provided answer helped, I have modified the code to the following in the confidence interval function and as worked:                                     add_ci(style_fun = everything() ~ purrr::partial(style_percent, digits = 1))